# Android FATAL EXCEPTION: main - Android Studio

Tags: android

I trying create MP3 Player but i have a errors in my Android Studio. I tested on Sony Xperia T3.
Please help! I don't know where is problem.. Error in FindSongs function (for(File singleFile : files))

```
821-821/dsada.dsada E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: dsada.dsada, PID: 821
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at dsada.dsada.MainActivity.findSongs(MainActivity.java:63)
            at dsada.dsada.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
```

My code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String[] items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        /*String[] items = {"stachu"};
                        ListAdapter laftyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
                        ListView laftyView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                        laftyView.setAdapter(laftyAdapter);*/

                        ArrayList<File> mySongs = findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                        items = new String[mySongs.size()];

                        for(int i = 0; i < mySongs.size(); i++)
                        {
                            toast(mySongs.get(i).getName().toString());
                            items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString();
                        }

                        ListAdapter laftyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
                        ListView laftyView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                        laftyView.setAdapter(laftyAdapter);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    public void toast(String text)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    public ArrayList<File> findSongs(File root) {
        ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] files = root.listFiles();

        for(File singleFile : files)
        {
            if(singleFile.isDirectory())
            {
                al.addAll(findSongs(singleFile));
            } else {
                if(singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3"))
                {

                }
            }
        }
        return al;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is this failing on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Simon it's not really a null pointer exception error, it's a permissions issue.

Answer (score 3):

It's very likely you haven't added a `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to your manifest. Try adding that and your files should show up.

If you clarified what LOC is failing, I could give a more definite answer.

Comment: @KamilKowalczyk make sure you upvote and especially mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `root.listFiles()` is returning null. (I counted the line numbers from the entry into `findSongs` which the stack trace says is line 39 making line 63 the for loop.) As Pheonixblade9 has pointed out this is most likely a permissions issue.

That being said you should add a check to prevent this error from occurring. I would suggest adding the following code:

```
public ArrayList<File> findSongs(File root) {
    ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = root.listFiles();

    if(files == null) return al; // No files available.

    for(File singleFile : files)
```